# Playing with => ludi je?

Tags: prepositions

This came up on Duolingo a while back and I'd like to get the community's consensus.

The phrase they give for *We are playing cards* is *Ni ludas je kartoj*. So would *je* be appropriate when you are playing with a particular item? Example: *My kitten plays with a string* => *Mia katido ludas je ŝnureto*

If not, what would be more appropriate? I would think *kun* implies participation of the item being played with (*Mia filino ludas kun sia frato*) for instance, although in the case of my kids this could either have been they were playing  on the swing in the back yard, or she was dressing him up like a Barbie doll.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The question mixes up two things, which should be separated:

1) "to play something", where "something" names the kind of game, is just *ludi ion*: "infanoj ludadis militon sur la herbo" (children were playing war on the meadow; Zamenhof)

2) "to play with something", where "something" names the toy, has two competing expressions:

-*ludi kun io*: This is found virtually in older texts only ("la infano [...] ludis kun korbeto plena je floroj"; the child played with a basket full of flowers Zamenhof), 19 hits in the Tekstaro

-*ludi per io*: This is now the regular expression (31 hits in the Tekstaro). This expression is more logical, as *per* names an instrument that is used for doing something (like playing), while *kun* expresses company, usually of a living being.

Comment: So your point would be that _ludi je_ is not correct, and it should be _Ni ludas karton_ if it's a card game, and _Ni ludas per karton_ if you're playing with the cards (eg building a house of cards)?

Comment: @OliverMason Yes, precisely. However, there should be no accusative after *per*: *Ni ludas per kartoj*.

Comment: @Joffysloffy Of course! Silly me :)

Comment: @OliverMason No problem :).

Comment: @Cyril Brosch Thank you for your reply. So it sounds like instead of "Ni ludas je kartoj" Duolingo should have used "Ni ludas per kartoj", which makes sense, since I learned you should never use 'je' when another preposition would do. But one has to wonder where they came up with the 'je' version, unless someone just put the sentence together without checking it first.

Comment: I disagree.  Ludi je is not an incorrect expression.   It is meant when you play a game.  It transfers from Spanish like "Jugar al ajedrez" "Jugar a las cartas".    Ludi je ion is correct because it indicates a type of direct object with an implied indirect object.

Comment: @Creede
_ludi je io_ is not necessarily wrong. As you see from the attestations, there is some kind of dithering between _ludi kun_ and _per_ for naming the object, so this is a usecase for _je_. However, _ludi je_ should IMHO be avoided in meaning 1), as it is more clear to use the accusative here.

Comment: @Cyril Brosch In meaning 1) I would definitely use the accusative when you're talking about a particular game. _Ni ludas briĝon_ or _Ni ludas Monopolion_ for instance. I think where I've been getting hung up is, _kartoj_ is a tool for playing the game, not a game in and of itself.

Comment: @Creede I think _kartoj_ is a kind of grey zone, as you can mean both the instrument and (metaphorically) the game. I see no need to severely search a clear-cut division in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

Normally *ludi je* would be followed by the name of a specific game. As for other objects, one could vaguely say *je la ŝnureto* but generally there is no reason to when you can say *kun* or *per*.

- *La katido ludis per/kun la ŝnureto.* The kitten played with the string.
- *La katido batetadis la ŝnureton per piedo.* The kitten would bat the string around with a paw.
- *Ŝi ludis kun la fajro per la fajrostango.* She played with the fire using the poker. She used the poker to play with the fire.
- *Mi ludis kun mia frato je la fajro per longaj branĉoj.* I played with the fire with my brother using long branches. (Better: *Mi kaj mia frato ludis kun la fajro...*)
- *Li turnetis la gitaron en siaj manoj.* or *Li ludiligis la gitaron dum momento.* or *Li sencele manipulis la gitaron.* He toyed with the guitar.

Concerning cards:

- *Ili ludis kartojn.* They played cards.
- *Ili ludis je kartoj.* They played at cards.

No real difference there. I would interpret *ludis je **la** kartoj* as "played around with the cards" but it's difficult to decide out of context.

- *Li ludis la pikan ason.* He played the ace of spades.
- *Ili ludis briĝon, je Monopoly.* They played bridge, Monopoly.
- *Ili ludis per/kun kartoj.* They played [the game] using cards.
- *Ili ludiligis la kartojn.* They toyed with, played around with the cards.
- *Ili fingrumis la kartojn.* They fiddled with the cards.
- *Ili sencele puŝetis la kartojn sur la tablo.* They idly nudged the cards around on the table.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the answers given so far. First a few of them give very hard and fast rules where there is actually some wiggle area. Second, the others sound very speculative and/or don't refer to any sources.

Quite frankly, the Duolingo sentence surprised me at first, but I've come to the conclusion that the sentence is fine. ***Ni ludas je kartoj***

If the cat is playing with a string, then it would have to be ***per.***

The usual use of *ludi **kun*** is to indicate fellow players.

A good place to look for examples is PIV. There are several good examples there, including some interesting counter-examples.

- la knabino ludis kun sia pupo<sup>Z</sup>

It's true that the name of the game or category of the game is often given by the accusative.

- blindulo kartojn ludi ne devas<sup>Z</sup>

But there's no reason this can't also be done with ***je***. The exact phrase ***ludi je kartoj*** is found in [L'Esperantiste](https://books.google.com/books?id=H0yY9PySD3cC&pg=PA47&lpg=PA47&dq=%22je+kartoj%22&source=bl&ots=g71taJjH9j&sig=KtpKgcdQRv3IqPI-B8y3jGgkGfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBq4Dl3ovVAhVDPz4KHf0hBC0Q6AEINTAD#v=onepage&q=%22je%20kartoj%22&f=false). There are different examples in the Tekstaro as well. (Translations are mine.)

- La infanoj ludis je mono - The children played money.
- Ludi je soldatoj = To play soldiers.

In conclusion: *Ludi je kartoj* is correct. *Ludi per ŝnuro* is correct.

Answer (score 0):

*Ludi je* and *Ludi kun* are two different things.

*Ludi je* indicates a specific game that is played with two people, but you don't explicitly describe the two people.  You only mention one.

*Ludi kun*, as in an animal playing with a toy, is a completely different idea.  That is a toy or item that is played with by one person or animal.  It can also be used as in your example of one cousin playing with another.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to say *kun* rather than *je* but here are some examples from the tekstaro:

- Ĉu vi ne volas ludi je la animoj?
- ...komencis ludi je soldatoj.
- La infanoj ludas je mono.